# How to add color to specific part of text in span element in react?

Tags: css, reactjs

Hi i want to add color to only specific part of text within span element. i am passing this text as props to child component and i am not sure how to do it.

Below is the code,

```
switch(notification.type) {
case 'uploaded':
    return (
        <ListItem icon={<Svg/>} text={name + 
            'created item' + item.name} timestamp={timestamp}>
            <div className="image">
                <Image
                    width={70}
                    height={70}
                    item_id={item.id}
                />
            </div>
       </ListItem>
    );
case 'comment':
    return (
        <ListItem icon={<Svg/>} text={name + 
            'commented item' + item.name} ref={this.comment_ref} 
            className="span" timestamp= {timestamp}>
        </ListItem>
    );

function ListItem(props) {
    return (
        <li className="item">
            <div className="details">
                {props.icon}
                <span ref={props.ref} className={props.className}> 
                    {props.text} 
                </span>
             </div>
             {props.children}
             <Timestamp>{props.timestamp}</Timestamp>
        </li>
    );
}
```

From the above code, each case is passing text prop to the child component ListItem. Within the text prop i want the name and item.name to be in blue colors.
    text={**name** + 
                'commented item' + **item.name**}
 how can i do it? could someone help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reform the value of `text` prop as an object containing the 3 pieces you need to style differently:

```
<ListItem
  icon={<Svg/>}
  // text is now an object, contains data however you want to pass it in
  text={{
    name: name,
    commentedItem: commentedItem
    itemName: item.name
  }}
  ref={this.comment_ref} 
  className="span"
  timestamp= {timestamp}>
</ListItem>
```

Then in your `ListItem` component you can output them with markup that lets you style them how you need:

```
function ListItem(props) {
  return (
    <li className="item">
        <div className="details">
            {props.icon}
            <span ref={props.ref} className={props.className}>

              <span className="blue-text">{props.text.name}</span>
              <span>{props.text.commentedItem}</span>
              <span className="blue-text">{props.text.itemName}</span>

            </span>
         </div>
         {props.children}
         <Timestamp>{props.timestamp}</Timestamp>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to pass a component instead of a string in text.

```
text={<span>
    <span className="blue">{name}</span> commented item <span className="blue">{item.name}</span>
</span>}
```

Also, the code is a little difficult to keep track of. Instead of the switch statement Id do something like

```
const Text= ({name, itemName }) => <span>
  <span className="blue">{name}</span> commented item <span className="blue">{item.name}</span>
</span>;


const ListItemComponent = ({name, item, timestamp, notification}) => (
<ListItem
  icon={<Svg/>}
  text={<Text name={name} itemName={item.name} /> }
  timestamp={timestamp}>
  {notification.type === "uploaded" && <div className="image">
      <Image
          width={70}
          height={70}
          item_id={item.id}
      />
  </div>}
</ListItem>
)
```